# Tensorflow error:The graph couldn't be sorted in topological order

Tags: tensorflow

When I run my loss function and it will be occur this error or warning.
I really can not figure out what cause it.
I guess that maybe I didn't use the origin input,for example:

```
def loss(predict,label):
    #because some reason I need to extract some values in predict
    predictProcessed = process(predict)
    #predictProcessed is a subset of predict
    loss = tf.square(predict - label)
    return loss
```

My guess is right or not?
And I also use double for-loop in this code,Should the code use less for for-loop?
thanks

Comment: topological sorting is only possible on a directed acyclic graph, you might have a circle in the graph.